# What is more fundamental $E=\hbar \omega$ or $E=c\hbar k$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, bosons

Let us say I have a massless particle (not necessarily a photon) then in a medium where $\omega \ne c k$ (e.g. a dispersive medium) what is the energy of the particle?

As my title indicates are think there are two possibilities $E=\hbar \omega$ which seems comes naturally from the time dependent Schrödinger equation or $P=c\hbar k$ which seems to come naturally from the time dependent Schrödinger equation in combination with:
$$E=\sqrt{P^2c^2+mc^4}$$
with $m=0$ and $P=\hbar k$

Comment: I think you are answering yourself.
For example for the harmonic oscillator $E_n = \hbar \omega(n + \frac{1}{2})$, while the expresion using $c$ is specific for light in vacum.

Plane waves in other mediums, do have different velocities, but the relationship $\omega = v k$

Comment: The Planck relation is always true; frequency doesn't change unless the interactions are non-linear.